# Selenium Automation WebDriver Manager is not working for Chrome version 116

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have used this dependency in selenium framework.
but browser is not invoked because of chrome version is 116

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Chrome browser should invoke automatically

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution: Upgrade your selenium to `v4.11.0` in your POM.xml as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Having said that, if you use latest selenium you don't need `webdrivermanager`. Selenium's inbuilt tool `SeleniumManager` will do what `WDM` used to do (i.e. download and management of `driver.exe`). If you use latest selenium, code can be as simple as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");        
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need Java version 11 or higher to use WebDriverManager 5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I upgraded to 4.11.0 but still have same issue which is
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
"

edit : my solution is to use that

<selenium.version>4.11.0</selenium.version>
in properties

otherwise, older version of selenium was being used.

Comment: Please do not post an answer to state that you also have the same issue.